# How to assign an if statement's result into an equation?

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I have to run a program to get the correct interest rate based on user input and use the interest rate obtained to compute monthly interest earned.

For the computation of interest earned, I'm trying to use the print result to create a formula for calculating monthly interest earned. However, I've tried so many things and I'm not sure how to correct this.

```
transaction_category = [2000, 2500, 5000, 15000, 30000]
first_50k_1_category_rates = [0.05, 1.55, 1.85, 1.90, 2.00, 2.08]

if (count == 1) and (account_balance <= 50000) and (total_eligible_monthly_transactions < transaction_category[0]):
    print(f'Interest rate applicable is: {first_50k_1_category_rates[0]: .2f}%')

if (count == 1) and (account_balance <= 50000) and (transaction_category[0] <= total_eligible_monthly_transactions < transaction_category[1]):
    print(f'Interest rate applicable is: {first_50k_1_category_rates[1]: .2f}%')
```

Comment: maybe re-think the logic for a moment, the `if` statement should select a calculation, right? The call of `print` just gives you information on what is going on - It should have nothing to do with the logic or mathematics I'd suggest.

Comment: yes, the if statement will give me the interest rate i should use to calculate the monthly interest earned. just not sure how to use the output in a formula to compute the interest earned.

Comment: what do you mean by output? neither `print` nor an `if` statement have an output (although `print` actually returns `none` I think).

Comment: output as in getting the rates i.e. first_50k_1_category_rates or
first_50k_2_categories_or_more_rates

Comment: `if` has not a _result_ (or rather a _value_), because it is a flow control _statement_, that is, a beast on its own.  ፨ ፨ So NO, you CANNOT use the _result_ of an `if` into an _equation_ (I'd rater say, an _assignment statement_). The code block following an `if`, on the other hand, can contain as many assignments as you want, and you can use later the values you have so bound to names.  See [tripleee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57442170/2749397) for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is rather unclear, but I guess you are looking for something like

```py
if (count == 1) and (account_balance <= 50000) and (transaction_category[3] <= total_eligible_monthly_transactions < transaction_category[4]):
    applicable_interest_rate = first_50k_1_category_rates[4]

elif (count == 1) and (account_balance <= 50000) and (total_eligible_monthly_transactions >= transaction_category[4]):
    applicable_interest_rate = first_50k_1_category_rates[5]

print(f'Interest rate applicable is: {applicable_interest_rate: .2f}%')
```

This is just a sketch; you will have to make sure the new variable is always defined, then use that in your final equation instead.

Probably the repeated conditions should be refactored, too, so you don't compare the same things over and over.

```py
if (count == 1) and (account_balance <= 50000):
    if transaction_category[3] <= total_eligible_monthly_transactions < transaction_category[4]:
        applicable_interest_rate = first_50k_1_category_rates[4]
    elif total_eligible_monthly_transactions >= transaction_category[4]:
        applicable_interest_rate = first_50k_1_category_rates[5]
```

but again, without seeing the complete script, it's not clear exactly how to refactor. This is just one example to illustrate the idea.

Comment: hi, i put in the entire code. hope it helps! i tried to do what u said but python is saying that the applicable_interest_rate is not defined. what should i do?

Comment: ooh, you gave more or less my answer 10' sooner, I feel like I'll +1 and remove mine...

Comment: The gist of this answer is that merely printing the decision does nothing to tell Python to use that number; you also need to assign it to a variable or use it in a function call or whatever. My proposal is to define a new variable and use it in the final equation. Like the answer already explains, you will need to make sure this variable is defined even if none of these `if` conditions are true. A common arrangement is to define the variable with a default value at the top of your code, then overwrite the default with a different value in those cases where the default is not correct.

Comment: Another approach is to set it to `None` and then make sure every code path overwrites it with a valid number. This will result in a traceback if some code path fails to do that, which is annoying for the end user, but much better than buggy code which produces the wrong result without any warning because you forgot to finish a set of code changes.

Comment: @tripleee thank you so much! your method helped me with my problem. thanks for being extremely patient!

Answer (score 0):

So you could do if/else in one code block, or turn those print statements into variables and return them. Both would say result as var name.

```
def foo(condition1, condition2):

    if condition1 < condition2:
        result = (1 + 1)

    if 1 == False:
        result = (1 - 1)

    return result

print(foo(1, 2))
```

- there’s better ways to do this in a more functional programming aspect like this: `(lambda :f"b:{b}",lambda :f"a:{a}")[a>b]()`, but it seems this code style is imperative so stick w that.

Comment: @tripleee i am just waking up and went from my phone to laptop, thanks for pointing it out, i fixed it ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are having trouble with scope, you can try this (safe) hack:

```
_scope = {
    "applicable_interest_rate1": first_50k_1_category_rates[4],
    "applicable_interest_rate2": first_50k_1_category_rates[5],
}

def foo(condition1, condition2):

    if condition1 < condition2:
        result = _scope["applicable_interest_rate1"]

    if 1 == False:
        result = _scope["applicable_interest_rate2"]

    return result


print(foo(1, 2))
```